# Hive query returns blank using Python, but no issue when queried directly

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

The query inside q works perfectly when queried directly (Hue, MobaXterm (SSH), Aqua Data Studio (JDBC)), however when I try running it via PyHive, the regex statement part doesnt work:

```
from pyhive import hive
import pandas as pd

conn = hive.Connection(host="", port=10000, username="")
q= '''
select evar43, user_id, pagename, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(split(evar43,';')[0], 'age=(\\d+)', 1) as age
from hit_data_raw
where evar43<>'' and user_id<>''
and pagename like 'tools|tools|tool%' 
limit 50
'''
df = pd.read_sql(q , conn)

print(df)
```

While `split(evar43,';')[0]` does give me the expected `age=56` type of result, the `regex()` command in its entirety for some reason gives an empty result, so `age` comes back empty. Just to reiterate, querying what's inside q works perfectly if queried directly and returns the correct result.

This is the table format:

```
pagename   user_id   evar43
Tool 2      2174246   age=56;ret=65;sav=500000;desinc=100000
Tool 1      2425226   age=53;ret=65;sav=800000;desinc=100000
Tool 2      2427115   age=59;ret=65;sav=250000;desinc=100000
Tool 1      620071    age=50;ret=65;sav=250000;desinc=100000
```

Can you assist in rectifying and explaining why this happened? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was a \ inside of age=(\d+)